# Как парсить json с динамическим ключом с помощью volley не создавая класс?

Tags: android, json, парсер

друзья помогите парсить json https://api.exmo.com/v1/ticker/ . Мне нужно  запихнуть в arraylist или в map первое поле (ключ), которая динамически изменяется и last_trade (значение), как мне в цикле пробежаться по объектам json? В инете не нашел конкретный пример.
вот мой код java

```java
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, exmoURL, null,
                                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("myLog",response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("myLog","onErrorResponse");
            }
        });
```

как мне быть дальше? Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    // берём коллекцию по душе, например:
    Map<String, Double> collection = new HashMap<>();

    // получаем итератор с ключами (именами полей корневого объекта)
    Iterator<String> keys = response.keys();
    // и разбираем в цикле
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String name = keys.next();
        JSONObject currency = response.optJSONObject(name);
        if (currency != null) {
            double lastTrade = currency.optDouble("last_trade");
            // здесь добавляем в коллекцию 'name' и 'lastTrade'
            collection.put(name, lastTrade);
        }
    }
```